# How to gently close Chrome using CMD or VBS?

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I'm having a little problem about closing gently Chrome in order to automatically clean cache.

I have a website that is not refreshing correctly, but it does if I clean the cache.

For now I have a .bat file with the following code:

```
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul
del /q "C:\Users\Francisco\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Users\Francisco\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
timeout 8
start chrome --restore-last-session --start-fullscreen
```

Now, I know that `taskkill /F` forces the process to close and that works but as soon as Chrome opens, it shows a message that Chrome wasn't closed correctly and asks me if I want to restore the last session.

If i remove the /f option, Chrome doesn't close:

> ERROR: the process with PID 8580 (PID secondary process 8896)
> Could not finish.
> Reason: This process can be terminated only forcibly (with the / F option).

So... I need one of two options;

1. Is there a way to gently close Chrome like pressing Alt+F4 using CMD or a VBS?2. Is there a way to hide that Chrome restore last session message?

I'd prefer the first option since it's cleaner.

Comment: Update: if I replace --restore-last-session for --incognito, the restore message dissappears but I still want to know how to close Chrome without forcing it.

Comment: The __TASKKILL__ option `/F` results in a __kill__ of Chrome process by the operating system. Don't use `/F` and __TASKKILL__ sends a __terminate__ message to Chrome process and then Chrome should terminate itself. The batch file should wait a second or two before batch file execution continues with deleting cache directory. Best would be to check in a loop with 1 seconds delay between each iteration and a maximum of 5 iterations if Chrome process terminated gracefully itself before batch file execution continues on successful termination of Chrome.

Comment: don't work without /F :(

Comment: Do you have ever looked on process tab of Windows task manager or using command __tasklist__ how many `Chrome` processes run when you want to terminate Chrome? Chrome creates for each tab at least one process. I don't use Chrome for myself, but have seen on another computer one Chrome window with 4 tabs displaying 4 simple pages resulting in 11 Chrome processes running and using in total more than 1 GB RAM. As one tab was closed by the user, 3 Chrome processes terminated. So you may need a different strategy depending on what is currently loaded in Chrome.

Comment: `"not refreshing correctly, but it does if I clean the cache"` Did you try "Ctrl-F5"? It refreshes the site with a clean cache.

Answer (score 8):

you can use powershell to close all windows with chrome as process name. It won't kill the task but gently close all chrome browser windows, like if you clicked on top-right cross. Here is the command line to put in batch :

```
powershell -command "Get-Process chrome | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null}"
```

Comment: I’d add ErrorAction after process name in case of no windows available `Get-Process chrome -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | …`

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the answer of @tuxy42 :
You can write with vbscript to open chrome browser like this : ***Open_Chrome_Browser.vbs***

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
siteA = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516355/google-chrome-always-says-google-chrome-was-not-shut-down-properly"
ws.Run "chrome -url " & siteA
```

And if you want to close it safely : ***safely_close_chrome_browser.vbs***

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
psCommand = "Cmd /C powershell -command ""Get-Process chrome | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null}"""
ws.run psCommand,0,True
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just browse URL

> chrome://quit/