# Google Chrome always says, “Google Chrome was not shut down properly”

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

I using in the VBS file script this code for closing Chrome browser automatically

```
   Set objExec = browobj.Exec("tasklist /fi " & Chr(34) & "imagename eq chrome.exe" & Chr(34))
   If Not InStr(1, objExec.StdOut.ReadAll(), "INFO: No tasks", vbTextCompare) Then
       browobj.Run "taskkill /f /t /im chrome.exe", 0, True
   End If
```

the problem is that when i reopen the browser always with

```
   Set browobj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   siteA = "http://XXXXXXX/"
   browobj.Run "chrome -url " & siteA
```

I have error

> Google Chrome was not shut down properly

What's wrong?

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to gently close Chrome using CMD or VBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044776/how-to-gently-close-chrome-using-cmd-or-vbs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the answer of @tuxy42 : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044776/how-to-gently-close-chrome-using-cmd-or-vbs?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can write to open chrome browser like this : ***Open_Chrome_Browser.vbs***

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
siteA = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516355/google-chrome-always-says-google-chrome-was-not-shut-down-properly"
ws.Run "chrome -url " & siteA
```

And if you want to close it safely : ***safely_close_chrome_browser.vbs***

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
psCommand = "Cmd /C powershell -command ""Get-Process chrome | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null}"""
ws.run psCommand,0,True
```

Comment: You would be better adding this answer to [the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43044776/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you for your remark and it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044776/how-to-gently-close-chrome-using-cmd-or-vbs?answertab=active#tab-top)