# How can I open a firefox tab with a shell script and close the tab after a few seconds?

Tags: powershell, shell, firefox

This is what I have so far:

```
Start-Process -FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList www.google.com
start-Sleep -Seconds 40

killall Firefox

start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Start-Process -FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList www.youtube.com
```

...

Basically I want the shell script to open a firefox tab of google.com, spend 40 seconds on that website, then close the tab and wait 5 seconds before opening up youtube.com.

I don't have any shell script experience, but wrote the following pseudocode. Any feedback on what the proper syntax/method would be would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
Start-Process -FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList www.google.com
start-Sleep -Seconds 40

Get-Process firefox | Stop-Process

start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Start-Process -FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList www.youtube.com
```

#### Note:

by default firefox has activated the session restore so when firefox starts after a crash (or after the stop-process) the restore tab will also be opened. To avoid it you must disable it:

Open about:config in the Firefox location bar
Type browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash in the filter box, or search for it manually
Double click

```
browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash
```

It should change from

```
browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash default boolean true
```

to

```
browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash user_set boolean false
```

Close and restart Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this vbscript : `Safely_Close_Firefox_Browser.vbs`

---

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
psCommand = "Cmd /C powershell -command ""Get-Process firefox | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null}"""
ws.run psCommand,0,True
siteA = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516355/google-chrome-always-says-google-chrome-was-not-shut-down-properly"
ws.Run "firefox -url " & siteA
```